# Why does calling delete instead of delete[] on an array of class objects cause heap corruption?

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management, destructor

Consider the code:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() {}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    ~B() {}
};

void main ()
{
    A * array = new A[100];
    delete array;
}
```

On Windows (MSVC 2010), it causes exception because `delete` calls `HeapValidate`, which then indicates the heap was corrupted. How and why does this happen?

I indeed realize `delete[]` should be called here, and of course then there is no problem. But why does `delete` cause heap corruption? As far as I know, it should call a destructor for the first object (`array[0]` or `*array`) and then free the whole block. What happens in reality?

Note: if class `A` only has default destructor, i.e. I don't declare its destructor at all, the exception does not occur. Regardless of whether the destructor is virtual or not. Both in debug and release build.

P. S. yes I know this is undefined behavior.

Comment: Probably because `new[]` does something different to `new`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is undefined behavior to call `delete` on a pointer created with `new[]`. The basic issue is that when you call `new[]` it needs to allocate extra space to store the number of elements in the array, so that when you call `delete []` it knows how many elements to destroy.

The library will allocate space for the management data in addition to the needed space for the real objects. It will then perform all initialization and return a pointer to the first element, which is not aligned with the block of memory retrieved from the OS.

```
[header][element1,element2...]
^       ^
|       \_ pointer returned by new[]
|
\_ pointer returned by the allocator
```

On the other hand, `new` and `delete` don't store any extra information.

When you call `delete[]` it moves the pointer back, reads the count, calls the destructors and deallocates using the original pointer. When you call delete, it calls the destructor for the single object and passes the pointer back to the allocator. If the pointer was created through a call to `new[]`, then the pointer that is returned to the allocator is *not* the same pointer that was allocated and the deallocation fails.

Comment: Note that the first sentence is all the standard has to say on the matter. All following is what a typical implementation might do; the standard doesn't mandate this and the details may vary from platform to platform or toolchain to toolchain. +1

Comment: Thank you! But it doesn't explain what role the destructor plays here. If it was as simple as you described, it would fail regardless. But it only fails when a destructor is declared, even with empty body.

Comment: Some compilers [optimize that case](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/03/66660.aspx).

Comment: @RaymondChen: That explains it! Thanks. You should make this an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Because it's undefined behavior. Anything can happen.

Comment: That somewhat answers "why", but not "how".

Comment: @Violet The "how" is hidden in the compiler internals, deep inside a massive codebase, and will be different for every compiler and compiler version. It's unlikely that anyone but Microsoft will be able to tell you what's happening behind the scenes for a particular case of undefined behaviour.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Indeed!